# Программирование копонента для Joomla

Tags: joomla, компоненты

Всем доброго времени суток! Очень нужна ваша подсказка. В Joomla есть компонент com_users, одна из вьюх которого во фронтенд выводит , только один профиль пользователя, а мне нужна вьюха которая бы выводила целую группу в которой два и более пользователя. Честно признаюсь, то что программировать компоненты Joomla умею но пока что мне не достаёт объективных знаний что бы сделать это на 100% самому. Пожалуйста кто знает где можно детально почитать как эти вещи реализуются, поделитесь ссылкой на источник.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный компонент COM_USERS на фронтенде показывает только(!) профиль авторизированного посетителя. Если необходимо получать пользователей по группам(с точки зрения програмирования), врятли для данной задачи будет уместно переписывать сам компонент,для этого надо написать новый компонент со своими задачами.Если нет 'возможностей' для програмирования самому, придётся искать готовый компонент (не знаю насколько это  будет актуально для проекта) напримере компонента Community Builder